# Date picker support desktop and mobile

Tags: html

Am using Html5 for an application. In that i have to use DOB field. My idea is use date picker that support both desktop, mobile OS.

```
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

Is this useful? Any suggestion for me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The new `<input type="date">` has been developed to be compatible with all kind of devices, both desktop and mobile, so you are right using this one for your app.

When used on mobile devices, it fires the default calendar widget.

Anyway, if you need more info, you can look at the W3 standard:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

Hope it helps! don't hesitate en ask something else!